# In-place patching of diff between two sets?

Tags: algorithms, in-place

For two ordered sets of keys Paul Heckel's [diffing algorithm](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359467) generates the necessary actions to transform, or *patch*, one set to the other. I am asking how you'd do the patching without keeping a copy of the *"old set"* around, nor incurring a large performance penalty. The problem statement is agnostic to the choice of diffing algorithm; the Longest-Increasing-Subsequence algorithm, or similar, could be used just as easily.

To illustrate, the first set could be patched **not in-place** using the following Rust code:

```rust
let old = vec![0, 1, 6, 4, 9, 3, 2, 8];
let new = vec![3, 5, 2, 7, 1, 0, 9, 4, 8];

let mut out = old.clone(); /* <-- Creates temporary copy. */
for action in diff(&old, &new) {
    match action {
        Insert(i) => {
            out.insert(i, new[i]);
        }
        Remove(i) => {
            out.remove(i);
        }
        Move(i, j) => {
            out[j] = old[i]; /* <-- Uses old set. */
        }
        Update(i) => { /* ... */ }
    }
}

out == new // = true
```

However, the above code clones `old` to refer to when performing `out[j] = old[i];`. This is unwanted since I am operating on a data structure that is unwieldy to copy.

Comment: One option is to have `Move` hold the old value rather than an index (and probably rename it to `Set` in that case), or, if you don't want to change the output, simply do this as a preprocessing pass. That is, loop over the output and do the lookup for each `Move`, the apply the changes as in the former scenario. Of course, both of these approaches can, in the worst-case, be tantamount to copying the input.